# my accounts are not listed in the etc/passwd file

Tags: users

I have lost most of my user accounts on the server particularly my very own personal account and all the files and scripts and .. that I ever created on the user. I have searched everywhere but they can't be found. please I need help asap.Thanks

Comment: If they are not listed in /etc/passwd they have probably been deleted.

Comment: If you did not delete them, then somebody else did. Check /var/log/auth.log. Consider revoking admin permissions from others. If you are the only admin then perhaps the system has been compromised.

Comment: thank you guys so much for your help but I still couldn't find them at all

Comment: my most obsession remains on the scripts  that I had on files

Comment: and just for a note; I don't have the /var/log/auth.log path in my server I have /var/log tho